# UITableViewCells animating at different rate than collapsing tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, autolayout

I am trying ot troubleshoot a tableView header (pink) that is animating a collapse. As the tableViewHeader height is shrinking the table view cells should pull up with the top of their tableView (orange). The beginning and end states are correct, but somehow the table view cells are animating up at a different rate. Something is clearly wrong here, I just can't seem to pinpoint what it is.

It appears to have something to do with the fact that I am using self sizing table view cells and `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. If I use fixed height cells everything is fine.

Beginning State:

[image]

Middle State (Note cells already sliding under header):

[image]

Final State (Final state of layout is correct):
[image]

Here is the code that animates the collapse.

```
 func collapseHeader() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        if let header = self.tableView.tableHeaderView as? TopicTableHeaderView {
            header.setHeaderState(state: .collapsed)
        }

        self.sizeHeaderToFit()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }) { (bool) in
        print("collapse completed")
    }
}

 func sizeHeaderToFit() {

    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var frame = headerView.frame
        frame.size.height = height

        if headerView.frame.height != height {
            headerView.frame = frame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
            headerView.setNeedsLayout()
            headerView.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And the problem was simply where I was calling `self.tableView.beginUpdates()`. I moved that to the line directly above `self.tableView.endUpdates()` and that solved the problem.